# Function `dir()` return garbled result

Tags: r, directory

when i use function `dir()`, it return  garbled result  and  there is no parmater to seting encoding in function `dir()`. How to solve it ? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The `dir()` function probably uses the encoding set in `options()`. Try setting it there.

Comment: @dcarlson6    thanks for your help ,but it's seems 'options(encoding = 'UTF-8')' can't work!